# Thor comic book (1960ish) in which Thor resists an alien weapon

Tags: story-identification, marvel

In or before 1961 I spent some time at a Boys Club in Philadelphia, and one thing I did there was read comic books.

I remember a Thor comic book in which aliens (possibly the Kree or the Skrulls) were on Earth and Thor was opposing them.  I remember a scene where the aliens were using their greatest weapon on Thor but Thor continued to fight.  And one of the awestruck aliens said something like "Never before, since time's first dawning, has any being displayed such power!"

And I remember thinking what a great exaggeration that was.  How could anyone know more than a tiny, insignificent proportion of all that has happened since the universe began?

I kind of feel like saying something like "Never before or after, since time's first dawning, has any being uttered such exreme hyperbole!", but my knowledge of comics makes me suspect that there are probably even greater examples.

So can anyone identify the Thor story with such hyperbole?

Comment: https://www.comics.org/issue/22975/?

Comment: Odin rambles on about mortal foes facing Asgard '*Since Time's First Dawning*" in Thor #145. I suspect it's an overused phrase.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is [Thor Vol.1 #131](https://marvel.fandom.com/wiki/Thor_Vol_1_131) (1966), specifically the story "*They Strike from Space!*" in which Thor resists a [Rigellian](https://marvel.fandom.com/wiki/Rigellians) psychic weapon and the aliens are impressed, with one of them stating:

> **"Behold!** He begins to **rise!** He threatens to break the **Mind Thrust!"**
>
> "Never -- since time's first dawning -- has any living being displayed such **power!"**
> [image]

Comment: That was published around 1966.  If the OPs timeline is right, it couldn't be a Marvel version of Thor which didn't appear until 1962.  DC had a version (also drawn by Kirby) as early as 1957, but i don't see Thor vs Aliens.  There are Alien stories without Thor in "Tales of the Unexpected" (#16 First appearance)

Comment: @SteveV - I suspect we'll see shortly that OP got the date wrong. There's no way they recycled a line (and circumstance) this closely within the same serial.

Comment: I guess this must be it, even though I thought I remembered it from a few years earlier.

Comment: @SteveV - And this is why you should never trust OP when they say that it couldn't possibly have been before x or after y. People's memories play tricks, especially when they've read lots of similar comics.